# asp.net remote validation only for one page

Tags: asp.net-core, remote-validation

I used remote validation, but I want use it in just Specified page not in other pages.
How can I do that ?!?!

```
[Remote("IsUserExistsByEmail", "User")]

    public string MemberEmail { get; set; }
```

---

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> IsUserExistsByEmail(string MemberEmail)
    {
        if (await _memberService.IsUserExistsByEmail_async(MemberEmail))
        {
            return Json($"Email {MemberEmail} is already in use.");
        }

        return Json(true);
    }
```

Comment: I believe you need to create custom validation for this :)

Comment: `I used remote validation, I want use it in just Specified page not in other pages` In your remote action method `IsUserExistsByEmail`, you can try to get the ***Referer*** request header with `Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Referer", out var referer)`, then check the actual address of the page making the request.

Comment: I already did it , but I'm looking for better solution